# Accessing raw capacitive touchscreen data

Tags: android, touchscreen

I wanted to get access to the raw capacitive touchscreen data on my android app. I noticed the following link walks through the steps to do this.

http://huyle.de/2019/02/12/accessing-capacitive-images/

However, it uses LG Nexus 5 phone and requires flashing the android kernel.

I want to follow the example, but I have a pixel phone and I have never flashed the kernel. So I wanted to know if there were other methods of getting raw capacitive touchscreen data or if it was okay for me to just follow the above tutorial even with a different android phone.